Multiple GroupJoin / FirstOrDefault with LINQ and PostgreSQL resulting in "Could not be translated" error
I'm trying to join two different types of deadlines to my dockets with a query like this:
var dockets = _docektRepository.GetAll()
[some .WhereIf and .OrderBy]
.GroupJoin(_deadlineRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == "A").OrderBy(x => x.Date), x => x.Id, y => y.ID_Docket, (x, y) => new { Docket = x, DeadlineA = y.FirstOrDefault() })
.GroupJoin(_deadlineRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == "B").OrderBy(x => x.Date), x => x.Id, y => y.Docket.ID_Docket, (x, y) => new { Docket = x.Docket, DeadlineA = x.DeadlineA, DeadlineB = y.FirstOrDefault() });

The .FirstOrDefault() part on the deadlines is important, because I only need the closest deadline of each type (achieved in combination with .OrderBy(x => x.Date)).
Unfortunately, this results in a "System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression [...] could not be translated" error. Switching to client evaluation is no option because there are thousands of rows (there's paging applied to the query in a later step, but that's not the issue here).
It's working fine when using just one of the two .GroupJoins, like so:
var dockets = _docektRepository.GetAll()
[some .WhereIf and .OrderBy]
.GroupJoin(_deadlineRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type == "A").OrderBy(x => x.Date), x => x.Id, y => y.ID_Docket, (x, y) => new { Docket = x, DeadlineA = y.FirstOrDefault() });

I don't understand why it's not possible to GroupJoin more than once, what am I missing? Or is there a better way to write the query?
Any help is appreciated!

LINQ doesn't query databases and there's no EF Core code here, unless it's hidden inside the "repository" classes. EF Core neither has nor needs "repositories", it's an ORM, a higher-level abstraction who's job is to completely hide the database and give the impression of working with in-memory objects. Explicit JOINs aren't needed either. EF will generate the JOINs from  the relations between the entities

That means that if DocketRecord has a Deadline or List<Deadline> property, EF will generate the JOINs automatically.

I would suggest to use Query Expression Syntax here. When query has several joined queries it is more accurate and predictable.
var docketRecords = _docektRepository.GetAll()
    [some .WhereIf and .OrderBy]
;

var query = 
    from d in docketRecords
    from dA in _deadlineRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(dA => dA.Type == "A" && d.Id == dA.ID_Docket)
        .OrderBy(dA => dA.Date)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from dB in _deadlineRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(dB => dB.Type == "B" && d.Id == dB.ID_Docket)
        .OrderBy(dB => dB.Date)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        ... // your projection
    };


This works great, thank you! Just for curiosity - do you know a way to write this as Lambda Expression? I tried many variants with .GroupJoin, .Take(1), .SelectMany, but it always fails when I add the second GroupJoin...

Query can be simpler, if you have docekt.Deadlines navigation property.

Yes I know, but I'm not used to make it on the fly. This query is equal to two SelectMany. Try do not use GroupJoin with EF Core, only for generating LEFT JOIN and as you can see it can be done by SelectMany operator. Ask ChatGPT to convert my query to Method syntax or use ReSharper, which can convert it automatically. Warning, it will be ugly and unmaintainable.

I agree that such a query, involving complex joins, is much more better expressed in this manner but it's not clear that the two queries are equivalent. .GroupJoin is expressed as from x in xs join y in ys.DefaultIfEmpty() on KSX(x) equals KSY(y) into zs

Check official documentation Collection selector references outer in a where clause

GroupJoin is something that is not from SQL world, it can be translated in several scenarios and EF Core made progress in this area, but try to avoid and your queries will be simple and clear.
